# Generate PDF using QuickReport from a Windows Service in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pdf, service, pdf-generation, quickreports

I'm writing a windows service using Delphi XE3. The service is going to read from a database, generate a pdf using quickreport 5.05.1.
I plan to generate the pdf using TQRPDFDocumentFilter.

Everything works fine in a normal VCL application, but when I implement it in a windows service the service hangs (without any exceptions) when I do a QuickRep.Prepare.

I have read that it is possible to use QuickReport in a windows service, but I do not know how. Any suggestions?

Where is the code:

```
procedure foo
var
 pdfFilter: TQRPDFDocumentFilter;
begin
  with TForm2.Create(Self) do
  begin
    ClientDataSet1.Open;
    QuickRep1.Prepare;
    pdfFilter := TQRPDFDocumentFilter.Create(GetApplicationFolder() + 'test.pdf');
    try
      QuickRep1.QRPrinter.ExportToFilter(pdfFilter);
    finally
      pdfFilter.Free;
      ClientDataSet1.Close;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Edit:
I have also tried turning off "show progress" on the QuickReport as suggested in another thread.
Writing some code to catch an exception reveals that it indeed throws one. The message is "There is no default printer currently selected".
So this leads me to believe that the local system user that the service is running under does not have any printers installed and that this is the problem.

Comment: [Generating PDF with Quick Reports behind a Delphi Web Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401743/generating-pdf-with-quick-reports-behind-a-delphi-web-server)

Comment: Do you start your service with corect privilegies to alow it to write into files? On windows XP this was not the problem but on Windows Vista and newer there are multiple privilege profiles in which services are started. They were implemented in order to increase the security by limiting what each sevice can do.

Comment: Bummi: I've already read that thread. Seems like he was able to solve it, but the information provided do not give any clues on how.

Comment: SilveWarrior: Yes the service got read and write access to the folder. It is already writing other files. However my code halts on the Prepare statement. It does not come to trying to export the PDF.

Comment: Do you have more than one thread in the service?

Comment: No only one thread. Please read my edited question. Seems like a missing default printer could be the problem.

Comment: run your service with a user that has printers installed?

Comment: Printers are stored in user's profile (i.e. per user). So the user used to run the service has to have printers preinstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved a similar problem (printing to a shared network printer from a Java server running as a Windows service) with these steps:

- log on as the user who will run the service
- install the printer

IIRC with Delphi applications, the printer name is not case sensitive (with Java it is).

Comment: Changed my service to run from a local user account instead of the default "local system account". Made sure the local account had a printer installed. I am not trying to print anything but it seems like QuickReport needs/checks for printers anywhay even if I only convert the report to a PDF. I was able to generate the PDF now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does Quickreport need a printer to render to the canvas?